# How would I resolve this kind of error? [Error number 11001]

Tags: python

I am trying to make a discord roblox tracker which tracks a roblox player and sends a message with a webhook that alerts when that specific player is online. so I tried to use "isOnline" from the robloxpy library.

but when I run the script it gives me an error (in which it says it's in like 519 but my script is only 31 lines long)

```
line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.roblox.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/1700848132 (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D0E02E6660>: Failed to resolve 'api.roblox.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))
```

This is the error ^^^

The `isOnline()` function:

```
def IS_ONLINE():
    UserID = 1700848132

    response = requests.get(Utils.UserAPI + str(UserID))

    try:
        return response.json()['IsOnline']
    except:
        return 'User not found'
```

Can anyone help me please?

I wanted to find the roblox player status with `isOnline` in robloxpy library, I was expecting it to work, but it did not.

Comment: There's no hostname `api.roblox.com`. I suspect the library is out of date, or the service has been shut down.

Comment: Isn't there a filename alone with "line 519"? The line number is in that file, not your script.